# Как в атрибутах тега хранить информацию, напрямую к нему не относящуюся?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Условно:

Существует некая переменная, содержащая количество очков пользователя. На странице есть несколько кнопочек, каждой из которых соответствует некоторое количество очков. Кнопка - это картинка, и при клике на нее серверу средствами AJAX передаются какие-то значения (onclick), производятся вычисления и возвращается ответ, в котором содержатся новое значение очков пользователя. При этом на кнопку можно нажать только в случае, если хватает очков. То есть какие-то кнопки должны быть блокированы. Таким образом, после каждого клика нужно перестраивать функционал страницы, блокируя/разблокируя кнопки.

Вопрос в следующем: как для каждой картинки хранить информацию о том, сколько очков пользователя она стоит?

Я храню ее в теге name = "999", но мне не кажется это правильным решением.  Неясно насчет неизвестных атрибутов, если задать атрибут какой-нибудь points, это будет поддерживаться?

Еще вижу решение, как альтернативный вариант, передавать id всех картинок, которые должны быть активными. Но мне опять таки кажется это нецелесообразно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну например

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.score = 100;
//т.е. придумываем свое свойство
//в нем мы будем хранить необходимое количество очков
```

Конечно же кнопки у вас скорее всего в массиве и т.д., но суть думаю ясна...
Менять обработчики думаю нецесообразно, как я понимаю вам достаточно просто на `onclick` сверять текущее количество очков с `button.score`
Я бы делал както так...

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, в самый раз должны подойти атрибуты вида [data-*](http://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

Скажем, если есть переменная **x**, указывающая на <img data-score='123' src="img1.png">, то через **x.dataset.score** можно получить или изменить атрибут **data-score**

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте кнопкам какой-нибудь атрибут, обозначающий id очков и передавайте его по нажатию на кнопку. А на сервере уже разбирайтесь, кто нажал, что нажал и мог ли вообще это нажать. Просто если напрямую указать кол-во очков, продвинутый пользователь может легко его подменить.